# MySQL query issue on left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the total amount per month from 2 tables Here is my query

```
SELECT date_format(items.date, '%M %Y') as month, 
COALESCE(SUM(items.amount), 0) as Rreceived, 
COALESCE(SUM(issued_items.amount), 0) as Issued, 
items.currency 
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN issued_items 
ON date_format(items.date, '%Y-%m')=date_format(issued_items.date, '%Y-%m') 
AND items.currency=issued_items.currency 
GROUP BY date_format(items.date, '%Y-%m')
```

I am getting wrong received amount. Can you please help me correct the query.

[SQL FIFFLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/518b9f/2)

Comment: so RRECEIVED items should be 100 right?

Comment: Yes, but I am getting 200 :(

Comment: The problem is you are joining on `date` so regardless of the join type you will get that result.  I think you should look into redesign your schema, probably add item_id to issued_items.

Comment: @Saleem could you be more clearer?

Comment: @bew I am sorry, There is fiddle link I need the amount totals from items and issued_items table. Please have a look at fiddle. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new answer related to the new http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9856e9/1 situation:

To avoid row loss I made a union on both table picking ALL possible month/currency combination, so I can do a left join on both table. 
Be aware, if a combination is not present in the union (Apr 2013/USD) no row is returned!

```
SELECT union_items.month, 
ifnull(items.amount,0) as Received, 
ifnull(issued_items.amount,0) as Issued, 
union_items.currency 
FROM ( 
      select 
      date_format(items.date, '%M %Y') as month, items.currency 
      FROM items  
      GROUP BY date_format(items.date, '%Y-%m')
      UNION 
      select 
      date_format(issued_items.date, '%M %Y') as month, issued_items.currency 
      FROM issued_items  
      GROUP BY date_format(issued_items.date, '%Y-%m')
) union_items
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT date_format(items.date, '%M %Y') as month, 
COALESCE(SUM(items.amount), 0) as amount, 
items.currency 
FROM items  
GROUP BY date_format(items.date, '%Y-%m')
) items 
ON items.month=union_items.month 
AND items.currency=union_items.currency 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT date_format(issued_items.date, '%M %Y') as month, 

  COALESCE(SUM(issued_items.amount), 0) as amount, 
issued_items.currency 
FROM issued_items
  GROUP BY date_format(issued_items.date, '%Y-%m')

)
issued_items 
ON union_items.month=issued_items.month 
AND union_items.currency=issued_items.currency
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT date_format(items.date, '%M %Y') as month, 
COALESCE(SUM(items.amount), 0) as Rreceived, 

  (SELECT SUM(amount)
  FROM issued_items
  WHERE date_format(items.date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date, '%Y-%m') 
    AND items.currency = currency 
  ) AS Issued

FROM items
GROUP BY date_format(items.date, '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Since your JOIN results in multiple rows, it will keep accumulating the Rreceived total, which  you don't want. A sub-query is a better way to go.

Comment: Thank you I am not sure about the sub-query and you have saved me. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

@Stephen:
your solution issue a subquery on *issue_items* for each row on *items*, isn't?

I think this can be a cheaper solution:

```
SELECT items.month, 
items.amount as Rreceived, 
issued_items.amount as Issued, 
items.currency 
FROM ( 

SELECT date_format(items.date, '%M %Y') as month, 
COALESCE(SUM(items.amount), 0) as amount, 
items.currency 
FROM items  
GROUP BY date_format(items.date, '%Y-%m')
) items 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT date_format(issued_items.date, '%M %Y') as month, 

  COALESCE(SUM(issued_items.amount), 0) as amount, 
issued_items.currency 
FROM issued_items
  GROUP BY date_format(issued_items.date, '%Y-%m')

)
issued_items 
ON items.month=issued_items.month 
AND items.currency=issued_items.currency
```

**CHANGE**
IFNULL can solve your problem (as NVL in Oracle)

```
SELECT items.month, 
ifnull(items.amount,0) as Rreceived, 
ifnull(issued_items.amount,0) as Issued, 
items.currency 
FROM ( 

SELECT date_format(items.date, '%M %Y') as month, 
COALESCE(SUM(items.amount), 0) as amount, 
items.currency 
FROM items  
GROUP BY date_format(items.date, '%Y-%m')
) items 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT date_format(issued_items.date, '%M %Y') as month, 

  COALESCE(SUM(issued_items.amount), 0) as amount, 
issued_items.currency 
FROM issued_items
  GROUP BY date_format(issued_items.date, '%Y-%m')

)
issued_items 
ON items.month=issued_items.month 
AND items.currency=issued_items.currency
```

Comment: Thank you Ivan Buttinoni, I need you help again http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9856e9/1 is not displying the issued_item for July as this is not in itsms table. Can you help me here Thanks

Comment: see my "change" section

Comment: Thank you foe help, but its not seem to work as expected. I need to display the issued record for july too. But this query only getting the records that are in items table. July record is not in items table but only in issued_items table. I am sorry to bother you but if you could help. Thanks again!